# Paperclip - get attachment.url in active record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have an Inventory.find(id) and it returns all the data I need including the icons uploaded
using paperclip. However, the result is returned like this after format.json

```
    "icon_content_type": "image/jpeg",
    "icon_file_name": "images_(2).jpeg",
    "icon_file_size": 994,
    "icon_updated_at": "2012-09-21T05:00:22Z",
```

how do I include the "icon.url" so it will say something like

```
     "icon_content_type": "image/jpeg",
     "icon_file_name": "images_(2).jpeg",
     "icon_file_size": 994,
     "icon_updated_at": "2012-09-21T05:00:22Z",
     "icon_url":"http://s3.amazonaws.com/*********/icons/000/000/130/original/images_(2).jpeg?1348203622"
```

here is my model

```
    has_attached_file :icon, :presence => false, :default_url => "/assets/logo.png"
    validates_attachment :icon,
    :content_type => { :content_type => ["image/jpg","image/png","image/jpeg"] },
    :size => { :in => 0..50.kilobytes }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json), you can add whatever you need to the json:

```
your_object.to_json(:methods => :icon_url)
```

For more complex situations, you'd rather use a json builder.